# Is DisableBrowserCaching tag being ignored / overwritten?

Tags: caching

I am trying to disable cache for all Sitecore pages. I am able to do this through the code (through shared layouts) but I wanted to do it through just the config file. I came across many posts that mentioned setting `DisableBrowserCaching = true` in web.config would add `no-cache, no-store` to the response header. However, in my case it takes no effect.

I was wondering is there anything else I need to do along with setting `DisableBrowserCaching = true`?

**Edit**: Everything under caching section in content editor is unchecked.

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/what-does-the-disablebrowsercaching-setting-actually-disable

Comment: Could you please verify that the configuration is not overriden by a patch to check /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx?

Comment: @MarkCassidy - Unfortunately not :( .

Comment: @TamásTárnok - Nope. It is not being overwritten.

Comment: Do you have cahcing.enabled set to true? If yes try making it to flase reset app pool and see what happens with other settings as it
 <!--  CACHING ENABLED
            Determines if caching should be enabled at all
            Specify 'true' to enable caching and 'false' to disable all caching
      -->
      <setting name="Caching.Enabled" value="true" />

Comment: @MrunalDaftari - I had tried that. Setting it to false gives me null reference exception!

Comment: @MrunalDaftari - Also, looks like the issue with Caching.Enabled is long known. I stumbled upon this link: https://github.com/Sitecore/autohaus/issues/5

Comment: wow good to know @AkshayMahajan

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are building an MVC based site?

if so the renderLayout pipeline is not used, and this is where the Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderLayout.BrowserCaching function is called from, so since it isn't called, it will not have any effect

you could disable caching for all actions in a controller, or specific action as below:

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)] // will be applied to all actions in MyController, unless those actions override with their own decoration
public class MyController : Controller
{
  // ... 
}
```

Disable for a specific action:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)] // will disable caching for Index only
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```